# Create a form with no default action using Html.BeginForm

Tags: asp.net-mvc, forms, asp.net-mvc-4

I want to create a form which has no default action in it. 
I tried doing `Html.BeginForm(null, null, FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data", id = "AppForm" })` but it assigns the current action method name to the action part of the form and renders it as

```
<form class="ng-pristine ng-valid" id="AppForm" action="/Portal/on/application" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" novalidate="novalidate">

</form>
```

I have two separate buttons on the form and I am following this article `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/442704/how-do-you-handle-multiple-submit-buttons-in-asp-net-mvc-framework` to create a form but not sure how to create one which has no action.

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried BeginForm("",""....

Comment: Yeah tried that..It makes the action="/Portal/"

Comment: Yea, I am sure that if the action is null, "~", or "" then the default route configured at startup is used. Perhaps you can have a special route configured, just guessing.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Do you have to use `Html.BeginForm()`? You could just do it with html instead of using the `HtmlHelper`.

```
<form class="ng-pristine ng-valid" id="AppForm" action="" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" novalidate="novalidate">

</form>
```

If you have to use the HtmlHelper, you can override the form action like this:

```
@using(Html.BeginForm(null, null, FormMethod.Post, new { @action = "", enctype = "multipart/form-data", id = "AppForm" })) {

}
```

Comment: Yeah I can but I was just wondering if it could be done with Html.BeginForm